# How to transfer variable from background to popup and access it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension in `background.js` i have a variable `var a = xhr.responseURL;`.

It works, i get it with `console.log(a);`.

Now I try to get it into `popup.js` with

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var a = bg.a;
console.log(a);
if (a.indexOf("https://www.example.com") === 0) {...}
     }
```

but if i try to access it with console.log it isn't there, and if i try to do an iF, i get an error `a is not defined`.

How can i correctly access `a` in popup.js?

**PS 1**: in the `background.js` i have some more variables, which are part of URL, to which i send the XHR. Example:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var protocol = "https://";
        var middle = ".myservice.com/domain/"
        var end = "/data/";

        xhr.open("GET", protocol + savedApi + middle + currentDomain + end, true);
```

In the `popup.js` all of these variables are overtaken and used exactly so as i described - another example:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    var currentDomain = bg.currentDomain;
    chrome.storage.sync.get('savedApi', ({
            savedApi
        }) => {
        var domen = chrome.extension.getViews({
            type: "popup"
        });
        domen[0].document.getElementById("domen").innerHTML =
            "<a class=link href=https://" + savedApi + ".myservice.com/" + currentDomain + " target=_blank>Domain</a>";
```

and they all work! This is really strange for me.

Comment: How do you initialize `bg`?

Comment: not sure , whether i understood you correctly, but i add some more details to my question.

Comment: You initialize it in `var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` which is fine only in case your manifest.json doesn't have `"persistent":false`. Now show us how you initialize `a` in background.js

Comment: `how you initialize a in background.js`: that was the very right question - got an error, thank you!

Comment: I have initialzed it on the top of file with `var a = "";` but then declared with `var a = xhr.responseURL;` - after i moved `var` from the declaration it began to work.